# How to compute point-in-time values from time-interval data with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

We have some a table (`pandas.DataFrame` object) that shows CPU count and memory usage for a
cluster. Each row of the table contains start and end time
(`pandas.datetime` objects) and the CPU and memory usage for a certain
job during that interval (intervals may overlap as jobs are
independent):

```
In [505]: data.head()
Out[505]:
           created_at          deleted_at  vcpus  memory_mb
0 2013-11-08 18:26:34 2013-11-08 18:27:52      1        512
1 2013-11-08 18:27:53 2013-11-08 18:31:07      1        512
2 2013-11-08 18:30:24 2013-11-08 18:46:35      1       2000
3 2013-11-08 18:30:24 2013-11-08 18:46:31      1       2000
4 2013-11-08 18:30:25 2013-11-08 18:46:36      1       2000
```

We would like to create a graph that shows the total CPU and memory
usage for the whole last year.

This implies being able to know, given a point in time `t`, what is
the sum of the `vcpus` column for all the records such that
`created_at <= t <= deleted_at`.

What code can we use for this task?  What is the fastest solution?
(We have a few million records to process, so speed is important.)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Python list comprehensions, together with
NumPy-style whole-array indexing:

```
# load data
data = pandas.read_csv('accounting.csv', sep='\t', parse_dates=['created_at', 'deleted_at'], na_values=['NULL'])

# create array of sampling times, using 1-minute resolution
mindate = data.created_at.min()
maxdate = data.deleted_at.max()
tm = pandas.date_range(mindate, maxdate, freq='Min')

# for each point in time `t`, select all records such that
# `created_at <= t <= deleted_at` and then take the sum of CPUs.
num_vcpus = pandas.Series(data['vcpus'][(data['created_at'] >= t) & (data['deleted_at'] <= t)].sum() for t in tm)
```

This works, but has the disadvantage that we have to run the same
generator expression again if we want to compute, e.g., memory usage.
In addition, we are creating a lot of temporary NumPy boolean arrays
to hold the results of the date/time comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a pure Python loop:

- create an array of sampling times,
- create NumPy arrays for the values we want to compute:

  - one array for each set of independent values (e.g., CPU count, memory)
  - 1 array entry for each sampling time
- for each `DataFrame` row, add the corresponding value to the whole segment of array entries in between the start and end time

The last point can be reduced to rather simple arithmetic if times are
expressed as time deltas in seconds from some origin (e.g. UNIX
"epoch").

In code:

```
# load data file
data = pandas.read_csv('accounting.csv', sep='\t', parse_dates=['created_at', 'deleted_at'], na_values=['NULL'])

mindate = data.created_at.min()
maxdate = data.deleted_at.max()

# fill missing dates
data['deleted_at'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['deleted_at'].fillna(maxdate))
data['created_at'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['created_at'].fillna(mindate))


# inefficient conversion function
def epoch(date):
    return int(date.strftime("%s"))

# sample times, equally spaced at 1-minute interval
tm = pandas.date_range(mindate, maxdate, freq='Min')
ts=pandas.DataFrame(tm)
# convert datetime to UNIX epoch
epochs=ts[0].astype(pandas.np.int64)//10**9

minepoch=min(epochs)
step=60

vcpus = pandas.np.zeros(len(tm))
mem = pandas.np.zeros(len(tm))
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    t0 = epoch(row[0])
    t1 = epoch(row[1])
    ix0 = (t0 - minepoch) / step
    ix1 = (t1 - minepoch) / step
    for index in range(ix0, ix1):
        vcpus[index] += row[5] # vcpus @ index 5
        mem[index] += row[6]   # memory_mb @ index 6
```

This allows computing many columns at the same time, but still the
loop is in Python code and Pandas `.iterrows()` function has to create
a `pandas.Series` object for each row -- so could be inefficient when
the number of rows is large.